# What do you do at Room 3 in the Pickle Factory?

Tags: west-of-loathing

I tried doing everything but when I turn the wheel nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Clues to tell you what to do in each room can be found by killing the ghost residing the each room.

For the boiler room, you have to set the temperature to exactly 190 degrees. Do this by adding coal to the furnace and using the billows until you are over 190 degrees and the last digit is a 5 or a 0. Then release steam until it is below 190 and add coal one scoop at a time (using the billows after each scoop) until the temp reaches 190. There is a little temperature gauge between the steam valve and the furnace.

For the Salt room, set the salinity to 976 ppm. The first lever controls the 100's place, the second lever controls the 10's place, and the 3rd lever controls the 1's place.

For the Cucumber Room, all the vats must be equal. Do this by using levers one and two to set the right-most vat to 1, then pull the right-most level 5 times to equalize the three vats.

Comment: Thanks although I found a website and did this and I forgot to answer my own question.